# AHK - How to hold a macro while Physical Key depressed

Tags: autohotkey

What I want to do is this:

```
Numpad3::
    if(not GetKeyState("Shift" , "P") and not GetKeyState("RButton" , "P"))
    {
        SendInput {Shift down}
        Sleep, 33
        Click down right
    }
Return

Numpad3 Up::
    Sleep, 100
    Click up right
    Sleep, 33
    SendInput {Shift up}
Return
```

But for some reason it isn't canceling when I let the button up. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Send {RButton Down}` (or `Up`) to send the right mouse click, instead of `Click up right`.

Also, you don't want to be sending random `Sleep`'s if they are not really necessary, as it creates lag and makes the script inelegant and potentially unreadable.

Here is code which sends `Control` instead of `RButton` but it's only so I can test it within Notepad++.

Just replace `Control` with `RButton` and have a go:

```
*NumpadPgDn::
*Numpad3::
    Send {Shift Down}{Control Down}
return

*NumpadPgDn Up::
*Numpad3 Up::
    Send {Shift Up}{Control Up}
return
```